# Sub Projects in "MSF for Agile" Process Template

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

Our team has just migrated to VS2012 and TFS2012. We are adopting the "MSF for Agile" Process Template. However, there is one snag. We are a team of multiple Web Applications and we have been given a single TFS project to house them all. The projects all run within their own separate agile sprints. When I log into the "MSF for Agile" template website for our TFS project I see no separation. Everything appears together in the same product backlog. I.e. all application development will run within the same sprints. Any of the metrics and reports produced will be useless.

How can I separate the applications into different buckets while still keeping them under the same TFS Project?

Comment: ...like having separate Product Backlogs per application.

Comment: How did you manage that in your old system? Wasn't that another version of TFS? To split the project a bit, you could create subroot areas and iterations for each project/team and in addition to this, you could create Teams (admin overview page in WebAccess).

Comment: Why only one team project? I think someone doesn't understand team projects. It's possible that the best way to fix this problem is to make them understand.

Comment: @MikeR - We didn't have an old system for agile process. We have only adopted it this year. It is currently tracked manually using sharepoint. The "create Teams" idea you and aclear16 discuss solves a lot of my problems.

Comment: @John Saunders - We are an internal apps team and support over 60 small to large apps. Square peg, round hole unfortunately. And I know the next question might be "is agile suitable". Management has ruled on this and we have been told to implement it. Fortunately we won't be creating 60 "TFS Teams". There are about 6 major products we need to split information up for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MikeR mentioned, one way to do this is using teams as each team gets it's own product backlog view. I would also like to point out that this behavior is template agnostic; irregardless of which process template you use Web Access will function in this manner.

I would question however, the value in this. The team's backlog should usually represent all of the work the team is doing, irregardless of its origination. This will allow you to relatively prioritize work for your various projects against each other.

You can achieve the reporting capabilities you want by using area paths to indicate which application a work item belongs to. Alternatively you could consider adding a field to work items to indicate with application the work item applies to. In this way you can have the best of both worlds: true relative prioritization and application/product based reporting.

Comment: I understand you questioning the value of splitting the team's backlog. For our major products, assigned engineers do not often float off one product. Thus we will get away with this.

New team's seem to do exactly what we want. Would I be right in guessing that we could associate the same iterations for different Teams as long as the start/end dates are the same? I.e. it won't skew the metrics and reports when viewing for a single Team.

Answer (score 1):

I went down this path as well. It seems that there are no "best practices" available for a situation like this.

What we have done is to decouple the management of Work Items from the task of source control. We maintain one central repository for these items, and 20 different projects / solutions for source control. This loose coupling has made things quite simple, although it does require an upfront investment is project setup time.

In the main project, I established areas (the TFS term) for each of the 20 projects. There is a 1:1 relationship between these areas and each project. Assignments are then clear to each team member as to the locus of the items.

In order to tie everything together, it is CRITICAL to require code checkins to link to a work item. This ties everything back to the management of the tasks in the main project. Without this, everything will go awry. With it, I can follow changeset across these projects without difficulty.

To manage the builds, we have build definitions that manage the deployment tasks. Currently there are 52 build definitions to manage deployments for different customers. These overlap the 20 projects, of course. Within the applications, ALL configuration is stored in source control, using transformations, so that the builds are properly deployed to the customer sites with the correct configuration. The fact that the code is checked in to a different source control area is irrelevant.

Finally, in order to manage down the chaos of builds, I wrote a macro-based build controller GUI that enables me to simply select a customer site, and build the appropriate configurations. It was a bit of a nightmare without that bit of glue. Now just a couple of clicks, and the builds are all managed for me.

It took a great deal of trial and error to implement this approach, learning from our failures, and not repeating the same mistakes again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the case study Jamie. I realise now I will not set this up perfectly in a week.